# Using HTTPS to encrypt data sent from mobile

Tags: android, iphone, objective-c, encryption, https

I have an app that is on both Android & iOS. To encrypt the data that is sent to a PHP script, from the app side of things, is it just a case of adding an "S" to "HTTP://....." and then everything is encrypted when sent up?

Tried Google but couldn't find anything related. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't just add an s.

the 's' in https signifies that the connection is secured by TLS (Transportation Layer Security) . This is achieved via authentication using certificates and Public Key Cryptography.

See:

http://computer.howstuffworks.com/encryption.htm

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography

for IOS specific implementations see

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH204-TP9